# how to keep newline in Json object

Tags: php, sql-server, json, curl

In my php code on linux, I submitted a CURL request with a Json object to a webservice.

A string was based 64 encoded in the JSON object. The web service then put the string received into a mssql database.

In the database, I found the `\n` (new line) was replaced. I wonder how to keep the newlines of the string into the mssql database so that when it was retrieved later on, newlines are shown.

I tried to replace `\n` as `\\n` and it didnot work. `\\n` was shown as `\` in the string. I also tried to replace with `<br />`. It did not work either. `<br />` was literally shown in the string rather than newlines when retrieved from mssql.

Here is the code:

```
$url = "https://<some website>/DocumentService/".base64_encode("#".$enmPatId)."/Document";
echo $url.'<br>';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
//$fileName = "QAChartRpt.txt";
$fileName = $enmPatId.".txt";
echo "fileName:$fileName";
$fileContent = file_get_contents($fileName);

//the following $fileContent has the newline in it
$base64= base64_encode($fileContent);
$postData = array (
                'BinaryContent' => $base64,
                'FileFormat' => $docType,
                'DateOfService' => $currentT,
                'TemplateName' => 'Notes',
                'DocumentType' =>'#1139'
            );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));
$res2= curl_exec($ch);
if($res2 != false) {
    //var_dump($res2);
    $response2= json_decode($res2,true);
    print_r($response2);
}
```

Comment: You have serious problems with formatting. Take care about it in your next questions.

Comment: It might be useful to see that code that is storing the data into the database

Comment: The problem is not with the way you send the data, but with the way it is stored in the database.

Comment: Lorenz Meyer, Do you mean that JSON sent the data correctly, but mssql database removed the newline?